# moving whole server to new one

Tags: linux

I have a VPS with cpanel VHM already and i am now ordering a new linux dedicated server with cpanel.

Is there a way to move my old server (inc. folders-files, mysql, ftp and other all stuff) to the new one in an easy way ?

Thanks

Comment: not a real answer... but I'd ask your host if they will do it for you. If you're managed they might do it for you for free.

Answer (score 1):

easy ... it depends what you have installed onto your vps.
for mysql you will need to export all databases that you use and import then into the new one.

```
mysqldump --add-drop-table --all-databases > my_mysql_backup.sql
```

then you can import it into the new server as (you need to copy the file from the old one to the new one)

```
mysql <  my_mysql_backup.sql
```

for the rest of the data if you are lucky you can just do a tar archive on the old and extract it on the new one.

```
tar cvfzp my_vps_apps.tgz /directory1 /directory2 (old server)
tar xvfzp my_vps_apps.tgz  (new server)
```

if you are not lucky because the OS version is not the same and you need libraries from the old system, or you don't have new apps for the new OS version it gets more complicated, but it can be done ... with more effort.